# Change value when click a button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code that increases a variable "money" when I press the key "S" and I would like to change the value when I press a button but it doesnt work.

Thanks.

Increases the "money":

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
console.log("Event");
if(event.keyCode == 83) {
console.log("Key Pressed");
document.getElementById("key").innerHTML = "<img src=\"stick2.gif\">";
shoot -= 1;
document.getElementById("shoot").innerHTML = shoot;
if(shoot > 0){
money += 4;
document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = money;
document.getElementById("cash").innerHTML = "<img src=\"money.png\">";
    }
  }
}
```

Changes the value:

```
    function onClick12()   {
    document.getElementById("ak").innerHTML = "<img src=\"ak/ak1.png\">";
    document.getElementById('b1').disable = true;
    if(event.keyCode == 83 && shoot > 0) {
    money += 8;
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = money;
    document.getElementById("cash").innerHTML = "<img src=\"money.png\">";
      }
    }
    function onClick13()   {
    document.getElementById("ak").innerHTML = "<img src=\"ak/ak4.png\">";
    document.getElementById('b4').disable = true;
    if(event.keyCode == 83 && shoot > 0) {
    money += 12;
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = money;
    document.getElementById("cash").innerHTML = "<img src=\"money.png\">";
        }
      }
```

Buttons:

```
<input type="button" onclick="onClick12()" id="b1" value="Use">
<input type="button" onclick="onClick13()" id="b4" value="Use">
```

Comment: You wish to change the money variable ?
Can you try replacing the functions names :

 function onClick13(event) {...}
 function onClick12(event) {...}

Comment: Ok I will try it thanks !

Comment: I think i got a mistake - You are clicking a button right, WHY you need event.keyCode in that button click ?
You could have removed this check right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(event.keyCode == 83 && shoot > 0)
```

The variable event is not defined in the scope of you function onClick12/13
Note that if you still get the event datas from the onclick event you won't have a keycode since click event don't embbed keybaord information.

But do you really want your user to press a key and click for what you want ?
If so i suggest you to have catch a keydown event to register in a variable the key currently pressed and a keyup event to reset that value.

That variable should be defined outside the function so the other function can access it. Here is the basic stuff

```
var key83Pressed = false;
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    key83Pressed = event.keyCode == 83;


}
function onCLick12(){
    if(key83Pressed){

    }
} 
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event){

    if(event.keyCode==83){
          key83Pressed  = false;
    }

});
```

Comment: If I make an other keydown event inside onClick function will it work

Comment: Nope this isn't how it works. that means that every time you will click you will bind a new listener listening for key events. This means that this won't work until you have click at least once on the button and you will have a memory leak.